# ActiveMQ 5.9.1 Drop a slow consumer on queue

Tags: apache, queue, activemq-classic

In ActiveMQ, I have a queue with 10 consumers, 2 consumers are blocked and etsan no longer taking tickets which were blocked with a certain amount, it causes other consumers are slow or times not work properly because they can not get these tickets for processing, my question is: how do I delete these two consumers without restarting the application of ActiveMQ ?, and I can not lose those tickets

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you've deployed the client, might be able to pause the listener (assuming you can identify the correct listener thread) or even put something that blocks the listener from consuming anymore messages (by literally never returning or throwing an exception to cause the thread to die).

However, JEE might be more difficult...

So how is it implemented?

Comment: I got a chance to stop the application with consumers, but apparently those same threads were blocked because the queue manager still appear these 2 active being that the application stop already is, everyone has blocked list 100 messages, so I see I'll have to stop the application of queues and affect production.